# jquery and codeigniter

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

and sorry if that question is stupid
I'm trying to use javascript with codeigniter and I can't get it right
what I'm actually doing is placing jQuery inside the views folder 
and call it from one of my view files 
like that:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
```

I get no response no errors it just doesn't work,  I could also display more code but my first assumption is that there something wrong with the way I call it...
maybe something with the paths?

any workarounds?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Place jquery.js in your website root and use:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery.js"></script>
```

If you want to put it say in a js folder, place the folder in root and do:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.js"></script>
```

Or you can try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?=base_url();?>js/jquery.js"></script>
```

as described [here](http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/62270/)

Comment: +1 - This is certainly a relative link issue, but consider using a CDN as well if it fits your situation.

Comment: but what do you mean my website root?
thats where it is already, it's in the same folder as the php file and I call it with:
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery.js"></script>

Comment: this is definitely a +1, because it showed me the right direction...
but I'll post an answer myself explaining what I did
thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Also consider that if you use Codeigniter's default .htaccess configuration suggested in the [Codeigniter URLs page](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

you won't be able to access a `jquery.js` file as a request for that resource will be rewritten to `index.php`; if this is a case you have to add that file as an exception:

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|jquery\.js|robots\.txt)
```

Answer (score 0):

i just want to add these tips from bretticu (in ellilab) beCause i was in a normal way using base_url();

That was running for my css, but not for my .js in a folder placed in the root.
So, after few gnashing of teeth and hair loss, i 've added two line in may htaccess before, now it's perfect.

`RewriteEngine on`
`RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|css|images|js\.js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)`
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`
`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1  [L]`

Here is the post of Bretticus:
[enter link description here](http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/197030/#926697)